# Python How to convert DST file into PNG file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I have looked around and read the docs about **pyembroidery**, and i am confused , so I ask here. Is there any packages available to use Python to convert a **DST image** to a **PNG image**?

## img.py

```
import pyembroidery
pattern = pyembroidery.read_dst("shamrockin.dst")
pyembroidery.write_png(pattern, 'shamrockin.dst')
```

Error

> pattern = pyembroidery.read_dst("shamrockin.dst",)
>   File "/home/panacea/Documents/src/easy tailor/EasyTailor/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyembroidery/PyEmbroidery.py", line 462, in read_dst
>                          reader.read(stream, pattern, settings)
>     File "/home/panacea/Documents/src/easy tailor/EasyTailor/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyembroidery/DstReader.py", line 86, in read
>       dst_read_header(f, out)
>     File "/home/panacea/Documents/src/easy tailor/EasyTailor/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyembroidery/DstReader.py", line 55, in dst_read_header
>       header_string = header.decode('utf8')
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Hello, what is confusing you about `pyembroidery`? I figure you can use `pyembroidery.read_dst(file)` to read your file and then use `pyembroidery.write_png(pattern, file)` to write it to png

Comment: how to generate png file

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: update your question with the code you are using. I don't have a dst file so I can't test

Comment: you can download dst file here   http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=30756946864522838433

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, always include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message).  There is useful information in there. In particular, it shows which line triggered the error.  As the question is written now, we have to guess which line is generating the error.  Is it the call of `read_dst`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write the PNG file to `'shamrockin.dst'`, which overwrites the original file.  When you run this a second time, `'shamrockin.dst'` is now a PNG file, so it can not be read with `read_dst`. (A clue is in the error message `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte`: the byte 0x89 is always the [first byte of a PNG file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header).)

Restore your original DST file, and change

```
pyembroidery.write_png(pattern, 'shamrockin.dst')
```

to

```
pyembroidery.write_png(pattern, 'shamrockin.png')
```

Comment: thanks it works, but every time logo color is changed

Comment: how to convert back png to dst

Comment: Those sounds like new questions.  The comments are not the place to deal with new questions.  Instead, create new stackoverflow questions.

Comment: @Sangram for the record, that's because DST files do not actually have color information in them. They are machine code of commands to send to an embroidery machine, and stitch commands do not have the color of thread to use. So I had it  (pyembroidery author here) choose some random colors if some conversion format needed them, as PNG does.